# Bash else/if capture exit status

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix

Please help me fix the 'elseif' line in the following script so that it can capture the exit status of zero and proceed without error, since I do not know the correct syntax to construct this.

I need to capture the zero from the following command, but within the parentheses in the script.

```
softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep restart
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH 
SWLOG=/var/log/swupdate.log

softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep "No new software available."

if [ $? -eq 0 ]

then
  echo "No new software was deemed to be available"

elif [ $(softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep restart & $? = 0) ]

then
  echo "RESTART will be needed"

else
  echo "Updates needed, but not restart"

fi
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions and ideas!

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -q` and avoid using `$?`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH 
SWLOG=/var/log/swupdate.log

if softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep -q "No new software available."
then
  echo "No new software was deemed to be available"    
elif softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep -q restart    
then
  echo "RESTART will be needed"    
else
  echo "Updates needed, but not restart"    
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to evaluate the output of your command twice, simply send the output to a temporary file.

```
softwareupdate -l > temp.out 2>&1
grep "No new software available." temp.out > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No new software was deemed to be available"
    exit
fi
grep "restart" temp.out > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "RESTART will be needed"
else
    echo "Updates needed, but not restart"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`if softwareupdate -l 2>&1 | grep restart >/dev/null; then` will do the job. You do not need to take the artificial detour using the `$?` variable.